# How to convert Expression<Func<T1, U>> to Expression<Func<T2, U>>?

Tags: c#, linq-expressions

Consider the sample project below. Given an expression of `Expression<Func<T, U>>` I want to create an expression that can be called for any `T` that implements the root interface (`IBase`).

### The problem

The expression converters below **seem** to work, but when invoked in more advanced expressions the converted `Func` throws `InvalidOperationException`. So far I have not been able to reproduce this. Though, looking at the resulting expression I do see that there are two parameters - `t` and `Param_0` - which I assume somehow causes a problem.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'variable 't' of type 'IBase'
>   referenced from scope 'Name', but it is not defined'

The convert methods below must be improved somehow. Please advise!

```
namespace ExpressionTest
{
    interface IBase
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    interface IFoo : IBase
    {
        string Foo { get; set; }
    }

    interface IBar : IBase
    {
        string Bar { get; set; }
    }

    class FooImpl : IFoo
    {
        public FooImpl()
        {
            Name = "Name";
            Foo = "Foo";

            var e1 = Test<IBase, string>(t => t.Name);
            var e2 = Test<IFoo, string>(t => t.Foo);
            var e3 = Test<IBar, string>(t => t.Bar);

            var e4 = Test2<IBase, string>((b, v) => Stuff(b, v));
            e4.Compile().Invoke(this, "new");

            var name = e1.Compile().Invoke(this);
            var foo = e2.Compile().Invoke(this);

            // TODO: Use "as" operator instead of cast...
            // var bar = e3.Compile().Invoke(this);
        }

        public void Stuff(IBase b, string v)
        {
            b.Name = v;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Foo { get; set; }

        private Expression<Func<IBase, TProperty>>
            Test<T, TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expr)
            where T : IBase
        {
            var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IBase));
            var convert = Expression.Convert(p, typeof(T));
            var invoke = Expression.Invoke(expr, convert);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IBase, TProperty>>(invoke, p);
            return lambda;
        }

        private Expression<Action<IBase, TProperty>>
            Test2<T, TProperty>(Expression<Action<T, TProperty>> expr)
            where T : IBase
        {
            var p1 = expr.Parameters.Last();
            var p2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IBase));
            var convert = Expression.Convert(p2, typeof(T));
            var invoke = Expression.Invoke(expr, convert, p1);
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<IBase, TProperty>>(invoke, p2, p1);

            return lambda;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var foo = new FooImpl();
        }
    }
}
```

If the intermediate interface (e.g. `IBar`) is not implemented, it should just return the default value - this is not implemented in my sample code.

### Update

Basically, I want to mimic this:

```
string MyFooExpressionCompiledMethod(IBase b)
{
    if (b is IFoo foo)
    {
        return foo.Foo;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to replicate your error, it is hard to say what is going wrong. Using LINQPad with its Dump tool can help view your Expression creations and compare them.

However, it is not difficult to add the appropriate conditional logic to your generation.

For `Test`:

```
var iif = Expression.Condition(Expression.TypeIs(p, typeof(T)), invoke, Expression.Constant(null, typeof(TProperty)));
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IBase, TProperty>>(iif, p);
```

For `Test2`:

```
var iif = Expression.IfThen(Expression.TypeIs(p2, typeof(T)), invoke);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<IBase, TProperty>>(iif, p2, p1);
```

Comment: I found the error. I accidently used the outer parameters when extracting an inner invocation which was later used. Thanks for the `TypeIs` code. Is the second test for a `void` method?

Comment: @l33t Yes, for your `Test2` method that has an `Action` parameter.